# images are not added in copy bundle resources in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am adding the images in my IMAGES group in xcode project but when i add the images into that group my images are not shown in the **"Copy build resources"** in Build phases but how can images will be added in Images group. I think because of that the App icon is not showing on my device?

Comment: r u adding those images in image assets folder?

Comment: How to add in image assessts?

Comment: Remember to select "Copy items if needed" while adding images

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image has your target (**Target Membership**) checked if in the right most panel for it to be copied into your .ipa.

Update:
In the Project Navigator, find your .png file and look for this section in the left panel (Utilities):

[image]

Comment: How to check targets?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add image, in your target -> press on Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resource ->  press on + sign and add your image..see below image

[image]